# D3: Brushing already zoomed data

Tags: d3.js, zooming, visualization, brush

I am trying to implement zooming and Linking&Brushing in Bubble chart.

Aplaying linking and brushing while data are still on initial position works just fine. Also zooming alone works just fine.
But if I zoom the chart and then i try to select the data, then it's not selecting the right ones. 
Example:

[Brushing while zooming is not applied](https://uploadpie.com/Fdjb31)

[Bushing after zooming was applied](https://uploadpie.com/dUOnim)

I am using brush.extent() to get the position of brushing space. Somehow the position of dots is never updated, while zooming.

I can take under consideration the scale size while I am brushing. But I am asking if there is something which updates the dots position after zooming automatically. Or am I missing something as I am pretty new at using d3.js and also on visualization field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same error, maybe my solution will be helful.

While brushing I add the translate values to the x and y coordinates.

```
d3.event.translate
```